# Preventing script injections in HTML form

Tags: php, forms

I have a HTML form which essentially searches for posts in WordPress. The markup looks like this:

```html
<form class="resourceFilters__searchForm position-relative" role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/search/'); ?>" method="get">
  <input class="resourceFilters__searchForm-input" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search" />
  <input class="resourceFilters__searchForm-btn" type="image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/vectors/search-icon-bold.svg "; ?>" alt="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="p_type" value="Resources" />
</form>
```

In this textfield, I ran a test and tried to search `<script>alert(1);</script>` which executed on search - not ideal.

To prevent `scripts` from being processed in this textfield, I tried the following:

```html
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'intercept_banned_keywords' );

function intercept_banned_keywords ($query) {
  $banned = array ('<script>', 'alert');
  if ( in_array ($query->query_vars['s'], $banned) ){
    $query->s = '';
  }
}
```

But no luck. `scripts` are still parsable in the textfield.

How can I prevent scripts from being allowed / searched in a field?

Comment: I'd suggest you to avoid coming up with your own implementation since an attacker can easily bypass that. Use existing function to sanitize the input e.g [sanitize_text_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/)

Comment: Hi @LS_ - May be a stupid question but, what am I sanitizing exactly and where? For example, in my HTML, where would I have `sanitize_text_field()`?

Comment: @LS_ - Nevermind, think I figured it out - something along the lines of `$keyword = $_GET['keyword']; $keyword = sanitize_text_field($keyword);`

Comment: yes, If you have a custom template where you print the value of `$_GET['keyword'];` sanitize that and you should be fine

Comment: The form is not the problem. You must be outputting the search term somewhere on the page. You need to _escape_ that with `esc_html()`.